# creating a simple static app [facebook app]

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I want to create a simple app for facebook, something like [axa insurance](https://www.facebook.com/axainsurance)

They have a folder competition, where you click on that folder which then displays an image which you can share. Any ideas how to do this? I have no idea from where to start. Can anyone provide any assistance or any tutorials on it? it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like they bought this functionality from [North Social](https://northsocial.com/apps/). Why not start with them?

Comment: why pay for just a simple static page , better to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to create *page tab app* here: http://developers.facebook.com/
Facebook app are now a simple iframe pointing to whatever you want!

A couple of details:

- you should have an ssl certificate for https user (otherwise it'll
  give a warning when the user will be on your tab app)
- Adding the app to your page is not really intuitive, take a look over here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/ - under *Direct URL Example* to know how to do it!

**Here's a tutorial about it**

http://query2arijeet.com/2012/02/16/installing-your-iframe-application-on-your-fan-page-2012-iframe-facebook-apps/

You can google around "create facebook app for fan page 2012" or something like that!

Comment: any good tutorials on it , i cant find a tutorial for beginers

Comment: for the time being i am using an html static page , but i will workout something from my own server later on this weekend , anyway thanks for your help